# Partitioning an array into as many contiguous sections as possible

Tags: algorithm

Given an array *A* of positive integers, find the maximum number of **contiguous** sections under the condition that the sum of the first section is >= than the sum of the second section, the sum of the second is >= than the sum of the third, and so on.

I know dynamic programming is needed. I thought about brute force of computing all possible partitions and then converting this algorithm into a memoized version.

Another idea is to go backward through the array, starting with the last element as one partition, and then adding up elements until their sum is >= than the sum of the next section.

Any suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: What your last algo will do with (3,3,3,3,3,1,2)?

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting problem. It resembles to the original partition problem except that here the sum of partitions needs to be in an monotonically increasing order. The dynamic programming recurrence relation is given as below:

```
numP[i] = max {numP[i-j] + 1} for those values of j (1<=j<=i) such that sum(A[i-j,i-j+1,...,i] >= lastSum[i-j])
        = 1 for i = 1

lastSum[i] = the sum of the last partition in numP[i] solution.
           = A[0] for i = 1;

lastI[i] = starting index of the last partition in numP[i] solution; // this is needed to obtain the partitions in the solution
```

Here `numP[i]` represents the maximum number of partitions that can be obtained using first `i` elements of the array (array not zero-indexed). We recursively try to find all possible solutions considering the `ith` element of the array, and output the maximum number of partitions obtained. `j` represents the index from where the last partition starts. `lastSum[i]` and `lastI[i]` are already defined above.

Here is the java implementation of the dynamic programming solution.

```
void getMaxPartitions (int[] A) {

   int len = A.length;
   int[] numP = new int[len+1];
   int[] lastSum = new int[len+1];
   int[] lastI = new int[len+1];

   numP[1] = 1;
   lastSum[1] = A[0];
   lastI[1] = 0;
   for (int i = 2; i <= len; i++) {
     int maxIndex = 0;
     int maxPs = 0;
     int maxSum = 0;
     for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
       int sum = 0;
       for(int k = i-j; k < i; k++) {
         sum += A[k];
       }
       if(sum >= lastSum[i-j]) {
         if(maxPs < numP[i-j] + 1) {
           maxPs = numP[i-j]+1;
           maxSum = sum;
           maxIndex = i-j;
         }
       }
     }
     numP[i] = maxPs;
     lastSum[i] = maxSum;
     lastI[i] = maxIndex;
   }
   System.out.println("max partitions = " + numP[len]);
   int i = len;
   while (i > 0) {
     System.out.println(lastSum[i]);
     i = lastI[i];
   }
}
```

The program is tested for the following inputs and the results are given below:

```
(1) {3,4,7,1,5,4,11}     max partitions = 5 {3,4,8,9,11}
(2) {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,11}   max partitions = 8 {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,11}
(3) {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}  max partitions = 9 {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}
(4) {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}  max partitions = 3 {9,15,21}
(5) {40,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1} max partitions = 1 {76}
```

Answer (score 1):

A greedy algorithm as suggested in the question would not work. You might think that the last element of the list should indeed be a partition of its own but here is a counter example:

[16,15,1,5,7]

If you have 7 as one partition you end up with 2 partitions. But 16,15,(1+5+7) is a better solution.

I suggest you take a look at [Integer/Discrete Programming via Branch and Bound](http://www.sce.carleton.ca/faculty/chinneck/po/Chapter12.pdf)

You start from the last item, your branches are your different choices for selecting partitions (n for the last item), you check feasibility of a partial solution by considering the >= rule and your objective function is to max the number of partitions. A good bounding function is that you assume all the remaining items will be partitions of size 1.

Another suggestion I have is to rephrase the question after reversing the list, it would be more intuitive. Reverse the list and change the rule to <= and start from the beginning instead of the end.

Answer (score 0):

I was initially going for a greedy algorithm, but indeed one needs to implement a dynamic one here.

Starting from the end seems intuitively easier. The main idea is that for a given step in the recursion, we have an established set of partitions, an ongoing one, and the rest of the sequence. Then, the algorithm must choose the fittest solution between adding the next (or previous element if going backward, which is what we do in the code below) to the current partition, and completing the partitioning, or terminating the current partition here and completing the partitioning (if applicable: the current partition may not be reaching the minimum sum to be terminated at this step).

We must keep track of the partitioning `p`, the current position `i`, the accumulated sum so far `s` for the current section, and he previous sum `s'`.

Here is a possible implementation in OCaml (code not tested):

```
let  partition_by_growing_sums a =
    let n = Array.length a in
    let rec pbgs p s s' i =
       if i < 0 then  1 + List.length l, l::p
       else let x = a.(i) in
       if x+s >= s' then
         let n1, l1 = pbgs p (x+s) s' (pred i)
         and n2, l2 = pbgs (i::p) 0 (x+s) (pred i) in
         if n1 > n2 then n1, l1 else n2, l2
       else pbgs p (x+s) s' (pred i)
    in pbgs [] 0 0 (pred n)
```

For memoizing, you need to keep track of the best partitioning done from each position onward (or backward), but this partitioning depends on the sum reached by the partition following (or preceding)  that position, thus any computation memoized would only be useful with a partitioning leading to the same state for this position. I am not sure this would be very effective.